# How do I consolidate/combine data when using a SQL join?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, join

So I have a table called Events which looks like:

```
Id   Date   Title Location
1    2014   test  New York
```

And another table called Quote Items:

```
ID Item_type cost event_id
1  paper     2    1
2  water     1    1
```

I have a simple join query like so:

```
select events.title, events.id, events.location, events.date, active_quote_items.cost
from active_quote_items 
left join events 
on active_quote_items.event_id=events.id
```

Which returns the data i want but each event can have multiple qoute items. I want to merge this data so that the cost of all items is consolidated in the column after the join. Is this possible, or is something similar possible?

Comment: You're using several different RDBMSs. How come?

Comment: You have one to many relationship between two tables using column `event_id`. So, you need to do some kind of aggregation on your `cost` field to group it together.

Comment: @FutbolFan, not sure what you mean? Wouldn't having the event_id be the simplest way to establish the relationship between the quote and the event?

Comment: its not clear what the output should look like.

Comment: What I meant to say is: the reason you are getting multiple lines of data is because of the relation between two tables (`event_id` column). So, in order to consolidate the cost you need to do some sort of aggregation  (in this case sum) like below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `Group by` and `Sum` aggregate

```
SELECT events.title, 
       events.id, 
       events.location, 
       events.date, 
       Sum(active_quote_items.cost) 
FROM   active_quote_items 
       LEFT JOIN events 
              ON active_quote_items.event_id = events.id 
GROUP  BY events.title, 
          events.id, 
          events.location, 
          events.date
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. I have a follow up question. How would I preform simple math on the sum? for example I didn't include it in my example but I have an estimated_cost and actual_cost column. How would I sum the difference between them? I tried using something like sum(thing) - sum(otherthing)

Comment: @AndrewFont - Yes that is correct. First give it a try and if you face any problem come here

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you could also use the analytic function `SUM() OVER` to do this:

```
SELECT e.title
    ,e.id
    ,e.location
    ,e.[DATE]
    ,Sum(aq.cost) OVER (PARTITION BY aq.event_id)
FROM active_quote_items aq
LEFT JOIN events  e ON aq.event_id = e.id;
```